# Invoke install4j updater with custom proxy settings

Tags: install4j

I want to do the following with application wrapped by Install4J:

- have the Install4J Updater invoked from the code of the wrapped Java app
- show the GUI dialogs, configured in the Install4J IDE to a user if there is an update available
- pass custom proxy parameters to the Updater, if required

As far as I can understand Install4J I should be able to do it with the following:

```
List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("-DproxySet=true");
args.add("-DproxyHost="+MY_PROXY_SERVER);
args.add("-DproxyPort="+MY_PROXY_PORT););
args.add("-DproxyAuth=true");
args.add("-DproxyAuthUser="+MY_PROXY_USERNAME);)
args.add("-DproxyAuthPassword="+MY_PROXY_PASSWORD);

ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess(
    MY_UPDATER_ID.toString(), 
    args.toArray(new String[args.size()]),
    null, 
    ApplicationLauncher.WindowMode.FRAME, 
    null);
```

but I keep getting the popup for entering proxy details.

I have tried changing parameters not to have prefix "-D", tried switching Updater to console mode or unattended mode, not passing the parameters but rather putting them to JVM directly with System.setProperty()... but with no success. I always ended either with proxy-popup or with message that "The update information could not be downloaded from ***_*__*_*** Please check your network settings."

Also: if I repeatedly invoke Updater but with different parameters the popup always shows the once I used for the first invocation.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the support from EJ-tehnologies (developers of Install4J) we got the proxy thing working. In the moment of asking the question we were using v5.0.11, and they instructed us to use v5.1.2 (latest stable build in that moment). And finally we ended using the beta release v5.1.3 (not publicly available at the moment).

Details on how to have proxy working, without popup and with using dynamic parameters:

- to the code above add additional argument that will prevent Install4J to detect system wide proxy settings:

  ```
  args.add("-Dinstall4j.noProxyAutoDetect=true");
  ```
- use method `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication()` for invoking the Install4J wrapper as it will start it in the new JVM. starting like this is required due to JVM's handling of existing env variables, so if you start Install4J in the same JVM and append arguments in that JVM the Install4J might not pick the latest values (this is if you want to dynamically change proxy params)
- wait for v5.1.3 to become stable and download it as it will support "not showing" of proxy popup dialog when proxy parameters are explicitly given to Install4J (this is my guess, I'm not speaking in the name of people from EJ-technologies)